# Transparent border with background color

Tags: html, css, border

This is strange.

This works:

```
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
/* renders a gray border */
```

But when I use it together with background color, then border is now a solid black line.

```
background-color: #333;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
/* renders a black border */
```

Am I missing something ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myxpXN

Comment: if you want a grey border then give a `rgb` or `hex` color instead of `rgba`

Comment: google material design, under color ... recommends alpha :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is that the background of the element appears through the transparent border. If you want to prevent this and clip the background inside the border, you can use:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:green;
}
#nav {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background-clip: padding-box;  /** <-- this **/
  background-color: pink;
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
header {
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <header></header>
        <nav></nav>
    </div>
```

More info about [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) on MDN.

Comment: Congrats on the relatively recent 100k!